# Excel Find and Replace #N/A

Tags: microsoft-excel, find-and-replace

In Excel, how can I find **and replace** cells with a value of #N/A with 0, blank, etc.?  Finding works fine, but when using the replace tab in the dialog box, the option to search for values goes away and I can only search in formulas.

Comment: If you no longer need the formulas to remain live, you can strip them out to leave values/results only. Once you do that, you can find and replace the #N/A values.

Answer (score 3):

You can always use `IFERROR()`. This will replace any errors with whatever value you choose. Just be mindful that it would also replace all other errors such as #VALUE etc. Use it like this:

```
IFERROR(yourformula, 0)
```

Alternatively you can use `ISNA()` to filter only for #N/A values, but it requires if functions and repetition of your formula  which can get cluttered:

```
IF(ISNA(yourformula),0,yourformula)
```

Answer (score 1):

`#N/A` is normally the result of a formula. You either need to correct / extend the formula (to give blank instead of `#N/A`), or replace the formula. Replacing the *result* of a formula makes no sense.